# Oracle join record in a date range OR get best record not in that range

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query getting data from a bunch of different tables.  One of those tables has a date that a piece of equipment was removed, and I get the last reading from it before it was removed, or the last reading if it has not been removed at all:

```
        join equipment_read rd
          on rd.config_id = eq_config.config_id
         AND rd.read_dttm =
                (SELECT MAX (rd2.read_dttm)
                   FROM equipment_read rd2
                  WHERE rd2.config_id = eq_config.config_id
                    and (rd2.read_dttm < eq_hist.removal_dttm or eq_hist.removal_dttm is null))
```

That works fine.  There is another table where the billing is done, and I'm getting a record there, if there was a bill made for the time the equipment was read:

```
        left outer join billseg bseg
          on bseg.sa_id = sa.sa_id
         and bseg.prem_id = prem.prem_id
         and trunc(rd.read_dttm) <= bseg.end_dt and rd.read_dttm > bseg.start_dt
```

However, if the equipment was just replaced, there isn't a billing record yet, and so I am not getting a match.  In that case, I would really like to just get the best record: select the record where my read_dttm is between the start_dt and end_dt **OR** get the max start_dt record where the start_dt <= read_dttm.

In Oracle, how do I do a query like that?  Is this something where I put a CASE statement up in the first part of the select, before I get to all the joins?

Here is an example of some data that I might be looking at.  For a record where I am finding a match:

```
read_dttm: 4/5/2013, removal_dttm = 5/3/2013
start_dt    end_dt
4/5/2013    5/7/2013   <-- get this record
3/6/2013    4/5/2013
```

and where I am not finding a match:

```
read_dttm: 5/6/2013, removal_dttm is null
start_dt    end_dt
3/29/2013   4/25/2013   <-- get this record
2/27/2013   3/29/2013
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i cant understand what you want, if possible, could you post a example with a little of data (tables-rows-etc)? Maybe i can help you more. If you can use [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/) tool would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I have *a* solution, but is it a good one?  (+/- votes or other answers will tell me.)

The second query is duplicated, once to get the data where there is a match within the dates (like in the question):

```
left outer join billseg bseg1
  on bseg1.sa_id = sa.sa_id
 and bseg1.prem_id = prem.prem_id
 and trunc(rd.read_dttm) <= bseg1.end_dt and rd.read_dttm > bseg1.start_dt
```

and another to get a match where there is not (and this is ugly, in order to do a max and left outer join at the same time)

```
left outer join (select bseg_id
                      , sa_id
                      , prem_id
                      , start_dt
                      , end_dt
                  from billseg bseg2a
                 where bseg2a.start_dt = (select max (bseg2b.start_dt)
                       from billseg bseg2b
                      where bseg2b.sa_id = bseg2a.sa_id
                         and bseg2b.prem_id = bseg2a.prem_id)
                   ) bseg2
  on bseg2.sa_id = sa.sa_id
 and bseg2.prem_id = prem.prem_id
 and mr.read_dttm >= bseg2.start_dt
```

Then I use a case statement in the list of selected fields and choose the results from first if there is one, the result of the second if not:

```
 , (case when bseg1.start_dt is null then bseg2.start_dt else bseg1.start_dt end) bseg_startdt
 , (case when bseg1.end_dt is null then bseg2.end_dt else bseg1.end_dt end) bseg_enddt
```

It's possible that there are still no matches, and I think I can live with that.  I just don't know if doing an assortment of queries and then case selecting the best one is a nasty smelly solution or a reasonable option.